# IE and Firefox display page differences

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Here is a link to my site: http://virtual.weltec.ac.nz/s13/Johnsonville/

Everything works well in FireFox, yet for some reason not in IE.
The main thing I noticed is the navigation bar at the top. In Firefox, when I move the cursor over any of the tabs, a drop down menu is displayed (this is done via CSS). This is not working in IE.

The wierd thing is, if I go to the map page, the drop downs work. But only for that page... yet the code is exactly the same in the other pages, and they do not work.

What would cause this, and more importantly, how can I get it working in IE?

thanks

Comment: "Look at my site and tell me what's wrong" is not well scoped question for the StackOverflow... But at least consider specifying versions of IE you have problems with - 6/7/8/9/10, compat mode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spot the difference - challenge accepted.

Well, whaddaya know, you're running it in QUIRKS MODE, no wonder it doesn't work. And the Map page? Yup, Standards Mode, and it works.

ALWAYS add a DOCTYPE to your pages. ALWAYS.